# read data from file and store it in an 2D array using static arrays

Tags: c++

I'm trying to read data from file and store it in an 2D array but it doesn't print the data from the file on the console the way it's written in the file. It says "Error reading file for element 10,11"

I've attached the file containing data that I want to store and print.

Can anyone please explain what seems to be the problem.Thanks!

```
#include <iostream> //in and output library
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream inputFile;
    inputFile.open("test1.txt");
         if(!inputFile)
         {
            cout << "Error when opening file" << endl;
            exit(-1);
            system("pause");
        }
        else{
            cout << "Successful in opening file" << endl;
       }

       inputFile >> boardSizeRow;
       inputFile >> boardSizeCol;

       const char HEIGHT = boardSizeRow, WIDTH = boardSizeCol; // the maze width and height
       unsigned char maze[WIDTH][HEIGHT];

       for(int row = 0; row < WIDTH; row++){
           for(int column = 0; column < HEIGHT; column++){
               inputFile >> maze[row][column];
               if (!inputFile) {
                   cout << "Error reading file for element " << row << "," << column << endl;
                   return 1;
               }
           }
       }

   return 0;
```

}

test1.txt

```
18
16
##################
#     ###     ####
#### ## #### #####
# ## #    ## # # #
#      ##        #
# # ##### # #### #
###    ####    # #
##  ######  ######
#### ## ### ######
#                #
# ## # ## #### # #
##      ##      ##
#  ## ###  ## ####
############# #### 
#   #       #    #
###   #####   ####
##  ##############
```

Comment: You are using undeclared variables. I don't see `boardSizeRow` and `boardSizeCol` declared anywhere. How can that possibly compile? Also, `unsigned char maze[WIDTH][HEIGHT];` is a [VLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) which is not part of standard C++.

Comment: The line `############# ####` contains a space at the end of the line. That ought to mess everything up. Also, the labyrinth has 17 rows and 18 columns.

Comment: ... and you've swapped `WIDTH` and `HEIGHT` in the two loops reading the map from the file.

Comment: @eden10 You don't have **any** comments?

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is a misunderstanding of how the >> operator works with std::istream.
The operator skips over white space.

I am not up to counting all of the '#' characters in your input file, but I would be willing to guess that you have 191 of them.  The output error is telling you that you successfully read up to element [10][10] before hitting an issue.  That means you read 10 complete rows (0-9) of 18 elements and 11 elements (0-10) in the partial row... Ergo 191 successfully read '#' characters.

If you want to read one character at a time and include white space, you will need to use the get() method.  (Watch out for newlines and carriage returns).

I have two additional suggestions for you:

1. Learn how to use a debugger to watch what's going on in your code.  You would have quickly seen that the spaces were not being read.
2. Visit the website: http://www.cplusplus.com.  It is an incredible resource.